# moving python3 to brew and updating

Tags: python, python-3.x, homebrew

I am running osx 10.11.6 (el-capitan) a long time ago I installed Python3 using the download on python.org (3.5.0) since then I've installed brew and would like to use brew to manage python3 instead. I have to upgrade to python3.6 because I'm getting the tlsv1 alert protocol version error.

1. How do I uninstall my current python3
2. How do I get brew to install python 3.6 (it seems to only want to install 3.5.1)

or is it better to just run different python versions beside one another?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) is the absolute best!

Longer answer:

1. (Optional: use Brew to remove whatever Python it knows about, just to save disk space.)
2. Follow these [macOS installation instructions](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#homebrew-on-mac-os-x). My simple summary:

   - `brew install pyenv`
   - add `eval "$(pyenv init -)"` to your `.zshrc` or `.bashrc`
   - restart your shell
   - `pyenv install 3.6.4`
   - `pyenv global 3.6.4`
   - verify that `pyenv global` prints the version you like.
   - verify that `which python` and `which pip` both live in `~/.pyenv/shims/`
3. Use pyenv-managed `pip` to install your favorite packages globally, like IPython, etc. (Of course, you'll use virtualenv to manage your per-project dependencies right?)
4. Happy Pythoning !

In addition to being able to have multiple pythons installed and a global default configured, you can even have per-directory overrides!

Summary: pyenv + virtualenv = the good life.