# How to install virtual environment with python 3 without upgrading existing version of python on my OSX which is 2.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

Is it possible to have a virtual environment setup with python 3 if my OS has python 2.7 installed, I am using "$ virtualenv python3env -p python3" but its trying to look for a PATH for python3 on my system. Is there a work around for this problem?

Comment: You could use something like conda.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Take a look at [`pyenv`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) with [`pyenv-virtualenv`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv).

Comment: I strongly recommend you check out pyenv too. My recent answer might help elaborate on why this is a great thing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49911429/500207

Answer (score 0):

1. install python3, DON'T delete your python2
2. after installing python3, make sure the to add the directory to PATH
3. change the binary(python,pythonw) inside python3 to python3/pythonw3
4. try to setup virtual environment using the same command in your post and you should now created a python3 virtual environment